# JQuery if next element is last element hide another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Keep clicking the down button here: http://thomasgrist.tumblr.com/ until you reach the end. The down arrow should disappear one click sooner. Any ideas how I can achieve this with the following code?

I'm a noob but I *think* that I need to right a condition into my else statement and say if index = something do this but I don't know what the index should be or how to write this.

```
$('#next').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $current = $('#listOfWork > .current');
  if ($current.index() != $('#listOfWork > div').length - 1) {
    $("#next").css("display", "inline");
    $("#prev").css("display", "inline");
    $current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
    scrollTo($current.next());

  } else {
    $("#next").css("display", "none");
  }

});

$('#prev').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $current = $('#listOfWork > .current');
  if (!$current.index() == 0) {
    $("#next").css("display", "inline");
    $("#prev").css("display", "inline");
    $current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
    scrollTo($current.prev());
  } else {
    $("#prev").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do this. Here is the code. If the next div index value *equals* the amount of divs minus 2 then don't show the next button. To hide the previous button when there are no more previous divs we write a condition for when current index equals 1.

```
(function() {
var scrollTo = function(element) {
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: element.offset().top - headerHeight + 40}, 500);}

$('#next').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var $current = $('#listOfWork > .current');
if  ($current.index() == $('#listOfWork > div').length - 2) {
//alert('Current index is ' + !$current.index() + '.');
$("#next").css("display", "none");
$("#prev").css("display", "inline");
$current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
scrollTo($current.next());

} else if ($current.index() != $('#listOfWork > div').length - 1) {
//alert('Current index is ' + !$current.index() + '.');
$("#next").css("display", "inline");
$("#prev").css("display", "inline");
$current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
scrollTo($current.next());
}    

});

$('#prev').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var $current = $('#listOfWork > .current');
if ($current.index() == 1) {
$("#prev").css("display", "none");
$("#next").css("display", "inline");
$current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
scrollTo($current.prev());

} else {
//alert('Current index is ' + !$current.index() + '.');
$("#next").css("display", "inline");
$("#prev").css("display", "inline");
$current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
scrollTo($current.prev());
}    
});
})
();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add this to the condition:

```
if($current.next().is(':last'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried: `} else if ($current.next().is(':last')) {
    $("#next").css("display", "none");
    }` but it didn't work, I'm guessing that's not the correct implementation!?

Comment: try to swap the order of the conditions, otherwise it will fall into the first if since the index is not 0